# ImportError: No module named base

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pageobjects

I'm trying to implement PageObject pattern for my first Login test. While running it I'm receiving the following error:

```
>> py.test -v test_login.py 
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.4
plugins: xdist
collected 0 items / 1 errors 

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
____________________ ERROR collecting test_login_logout.py _____________________
test_login_logout.py:10: in <module>
>   from ui.pages import LoginPage
../pages/__init__.py:1: in <module>
>   from loginPage import LoginPage
../pages/loginPage.py:3: in <module>
>   from base import BasePage
E   ImportError: No module named base
```

Here is the pythonpath:

> Pythonpath: PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/lib/python2.7/"
>
> > export PYTHONPATH

As far as it's one of my first tests a lot of code was copy-pasted, maybe there's something wrong with it but I'd can't get it. Will be very pleased with any suggestions on this point.

Also below is the structure and content of my so-called PageObject implementation:

1. **ui**

   - **base**

     - __ init __ .py
     - basePage.py
     - configs.py
     - wrapper.py
   - **pages**

     - __ init __ .py
     - loginPage.py
   - **tests**

     - __ init __ .py
     - test_login.py
   - **__ init __ .py**

> **ui/__ init __ .py**:

```
__author__ = 'testuser'
```

> **ui/base/__ init __ .py**:

```
from wrapper import SeleniumWrapper
from basePage import BasePage

selenium_driver = SeleniumWrapper()
```

> **ui/base/basePage.py**:

```
class BasePage(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def get_current_url(self):
        return str(self.driver.current_url)
```

> **ui/base/configs.py**:

```
import os

try:
    os.environ["HOST"]
    HOST = os.environ["HOST"]
except KeyError:
    os.environ["HOST"] = 'http://www.website.com'
    HOST = str(os.environ["HOST"])
PORT = ''
BASE_URL_US = '%s:%s/en/' % (HOST, PORT)
EMAIL = 'test.user@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'secret'
```

> **ui/base/wrapper.py**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import configs

class SeleniumWrapper:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(SeleniumWrapper, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def connect(self, host=configs.BASE_URL_US):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

        self.base_url = host
        return self.driver
```

> **ui/pages/__ init __ .py**:

```
from loginPage import LoginPage
```

> **ui/pages/loginPage.py**:

```
from base import BasePage

class LoginPage(object):

    login_page_link = '.log-in>a'
    email_field_locator = 'email'
    password_field_locator = 'password'
    login_button_locator = 'submit'

    def __init__(self, driver, base_url):
        self.driver = driver
        self.driver.get(base_url)

    def login_action(self, email, password):
        login_page = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.login_page_link)
        email_element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.email_field_locator)
        password_element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.password_field_locator)
        login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.login_button_locator)
        login_page.click()
        email_element.send_keys(email)
        password_element.send_keys(password)
        login_button.click()
```

> **ui/tests/__ init __ .py**:

```
__author__ = 'testuser'
```

> **ui/tests/test_login.py**:

```
import sys
import os
import pytest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../')
from ui.base import selenium_driver
from ui.pages import LoginPage
from ui.base import configs


@pytest.mark.ui
class TestLoginLogout(object):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.verificationErrors = []
        cls.driver = selenium_driver.connect()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        cls.base_url = selenium_driver.base_url
        cls.email = configs.EMAIL
        cls.password = configs.PASSWORD

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
        assert cls.verificationErrors == []

    def test_login_positive(self):
        welcome_page = LoginPage(self.driver, self.base_url)
        login_page = welcome_page.login_action(self.email, self.password)
        # assert 'property' in login_page.get_current_url()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main([__file__, "-s"])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `base` module is located in the `ui` module. Hence line:

```
from base import BasePage
```

should be:

```
from ui.base import BasePage
```

Answer (score -1):

i was just a beginner when this error struck what i did was
instead of:

```
from models.post import Post
```

i did the following after installing post as package:

```
from post import Post
```

it worked for me

Answer (score -2):

I was just a beginner when this error struck. So, what I did was:

```
from models.post import Post
```