# Can't import relative module

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

The file structure for a module im creating goes as follows:

```
PIV
| __init__.py
| base.py
| core.py
| exceptions.py
.gitignore
LICENSE
requirements.txt
```

But whenever I run a file like `core.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ghub4/OneDrive/Desktop/Python-Image-and-Video-tools/PIV/core.py", line 33, in <module>
    from . import base
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

The same thing happens when I run the `__init__.py` file. I'm not sure on what went wrong because all of the python files are in the same folder. Can someone clarify what's the problem and explain how I should fix it?

*Import code for `core.py` file:*

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image
import io
from . import base
from . import exceptions
```

(*The `__init__.py` folder has the same  relative imports as in the core file but also including: `from . import core`*)

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/5362583

Comment: After I followed the instructions, Im getting a module not found error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ghub4/OneDrive/Desktop/Python-Image-and-Video-tools/happy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PIV
  File "c:\Users\ghub4\OneDrive\Desktop\Python-Image-and-Video-tools\PIV\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import base
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'`   @Alok

Comment: Follow this one for the new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17525397/5362583

Comment: Thank you @Alok! This solved my Problem. If you want to recieve credit you can write an answer based on those links.

Comment: I have written an answer based upon the links. I appreciate your generosity on giving the credits :) All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the two links you will given below, here is what needed for the problem to solve:

- [Relative Imports error rectified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/5362583)
- [No module named base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17525397/5362583)

You need to import the package as this

```
from mymodule import some_useful_method
```

Sometimes, we get the `no module error`, in this case, we can import like this

```
from module_name.classname import some_useful_method
```